# Как ты там мой кóтешка/кóтюшка?

Tags: орфография

Почему *денежка*, а не *денюжка*?

Как правильно?

`Как там мой кóтешка/кóтюшка?`

Comment: Запятая перед _мой_, там обращение.

Comment: Надо читать словари, так никого не оторвёте от текущих дел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Тема:** уменьшительно-ласкательные суффиксы в разговорной речи.

1. Правильно: ***денежка.***

***Деньг/и*** — денеж/к/а, Е — беглая, чередование Г/Ж, К — суффикс.

Допускается в разговорной речи: ***денюжка***.

***Деньг/и*** — ден/южк/а, усечение основы, суффикс ЮЖК, а не УШК.

2. Правильно: *Как там мой **котешка/кóтюшка?***

***Кот*** — кот/юшк/а.  Суффикс ЮШК, сравнить: соловей — солов/ушк/а.

***Кот*** — кот/ешк-а, суффикс ЕШК/ЕШЕК, сравнить: край — кра/ешек.

**[Правильное написание слова «Денежка» или «денюжка»](https://inlermontov.ru/denezka-ili-denyuzka-pravilnoe-napisanie/#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%C2%AB%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0%C2%BB%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9,%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC)**

Comment: *Денюжка* стосоднимпроцентно инкорректно?

Comment: А как же, котюшка, надо?

Comment: Через *е* же! Викисловарь не признаёт *денюжку*.

Comment: Какой статус у Вики?    Пусть будет "денюшка". Усечение основы и суффикс ЮШК.

Comment: https://kak-pravilno.net/denezhka-ili-denyuzhka-kak-pravilno/

Comment: Whatever you say, kitty.

Comment: I am a kitten! A kitten!

Comment: And the kitten, too, of course. Don't be angry, kitten.

Comment: I am a peaceful one.

Comment: Kittens are always fighting. Such bullies!